# Find lightest paths from a vertex in a linear-time

Tags: algorithm, graph, computer-science

> Let `G(V,E)`, a directed graph with weighted edges (`w:E -> R`) and a `r` in `V`. It is known that **for each** `u` there's a lightest path (by weights) which is also a shortest path (by edges), from `r` to `u`. Describe an algorithm to find lightest paths from `r` to each `u`.

So what I thought about is simply running a BFS algorithm from `r` with a simple change; When we reach a vertex `v`, we sort all edges coming out of it and put vertices in queue by edges order (from smallest to largest).

This way we are getting a graph of shortest paths (As BFS should do) but we also prefer the lightest one from two shortest paths.

Let's assume my algorithm is correct, the problem is that it's not the most efficient one, since we have to sort all edges which summed up to `O(|E|lg |E|)`.

How can it be done in linear time (`O(|V|+|E|`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is the psuedocode for BFS from [Introduction To Algorithms](http://bayanbox.ir/view/4177858657730907268/introduction-to-algorithms-3rd-edition.pdf):

```
BFS(G,s)

    for each vertex u in V[G] - {s}
        do color[u] <-- white
            d[u] <-- infinity
            pi[u] <-- nil 
    color[s] <-- gray
    d[s] <-- 0
    pi[s] <-- nil
    Q <-- {s} 
    while Q != empty set
        do u <-- head[Q]
        for each v in Adj[u]
            do if color[v] = white
                then color[v] <-- gray
                    d[v] <-- d[u] + 1
                    pi[v] <-- u
                    EnQueue(Q,v) DeQueue(Q)
            color[u] <-- black
```

Your question states that

> It is known that for each u there's a lightest path (by weights) which is also a shortest path (by edges), from r to u.

Note that, by definition, this is recursive.

You can, therefore, modify it as follows:

1. Add to each node also `c[u]` (the cost of *u*), and initialize all to infinity. Also, add `cp[u]`, the "cost parent" of *u*.
2. When you encounter a node *v* in the adjacency of *u*, and *v* is not black, check if the cost of *u* + the cost of the edge is lower than the current cost of *v*. If so, update both the cost of *v*, and make its cost parent *u*.

Comment: Basically, as far as I can tell, we'll end up with some BFS tree where each node contains the `cost` of the lightest path, yet the shortest path might not be the lightest path.

Comment: @Elimination Right. Of course, if you need the lightest path itself, simply make a `cost_parent` variable, and update it if the minimum is updated - it's the same idea exactly.

Comment: Thank you Ami for the detailed answer!

Comment: @Elimination You're welcome. Please see update, though.